# Passing template argument to template method

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to pass a template argument as a template parameter to a template method. My code does something like this:

```
template<class FieldType, class FieldGetter>
FieldType getField(const FieldGetter& getter, const Data& data)
{
    return getter.getField<FieldType>(data);
}
```

Unfortunately this code doesn't compile.

EDIT:
My actual code uses some wrapper function on top of the above function. I now understand that using the wrapper caused the compilation to fail. I used your code(thanks!) in order to supply a complete example.

```
#include <string>

struct Data {
    template <typename T> T get() const {
        return T();
    }
};
struct Getter {
    template <typename T> T getField(const Data& data) const {
        return data.get<T>();
    }
};

template <typename FieldType, typename FieldGetter>
FieldType getField_posix(const FieldGetter& getter, const Data& data)
{
    return getter.getField<FieldType>(data);
}


template <typename FieldType, typename FieldGetter>
FieldType getField(const FieldGetter& getter, const Data& data)
{
#ifdef BUILD_OTHER
    return getField_other<FieldType, FieldGetter>(getter, data);
#else
    return getField_posix<FieldType, FieldGetter>(getter, data);
#endif
}

int main() {
    Data data;
    getField<int, Getter>(Getter(), data);
    getField<std::string, Getter>(Getter(), data);
}
```

The code above results with the following compilation error:

```
templateTest.cpp: In function ‘FieldType getField_posix(const FieldGetter&, const Data&)’:
templateTest.cpp:17:37: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
     return getter.getField<FieldType>(data);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code is terrible.

Comment: That's not very constructive. Why is it terrible? Why all the downvotes? Yes, it would be better if the OP had posted a [minimum, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the error message, but we can still make suggestions and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unfortunately this code doesn't compile.

It's hard to help without seeing an exact error message, but I reckon the problem is that `getter.getField()` method is not marked as **const**.

Below code compiles perfectly fine:

```
#include <string>

struct Data {
    template <typename T> T get() const {
        return T();
    }
};
struct Getter {
    template <typename T> T getField(const Data& data) const {
        return data.get<T>();
    }
};

template <typename FieldType, typename FieldGetter>
FieldType getField_posix(const FieldGetter& getter, const Data& data)
{
    return getter.template getField<FieldType>(data);
}

template <typename FieldType, typename FieldGetter>
FieldType getField(const FieldGetter& getter, const Data& data)
{
#ifdef BUILD_OTHER
    return getField_other<FieldType, FieldGetter>(getter, data);
#else
    return getField_posix<FieldType, FieldGetter>(getter, data);
#endif
}

int main() {
    Data data;
    getField<int, Getter>(Getter(), data);
    getField<std::string, Getter>(Getter(), data);
}
```

**Update:** I'm not much into template code rules, but from error message it was clear that compiler doesn't see nested getField() as a template method, so you have to state it explicitly (above code updated).